# How to switch light on by standing on a mat

Tags: switches, light

I'm working on a project for school. And I have this dance matt. As long as you stand on that matt the light should go on and stay on until you step off the matt again. But I have no idea how to make this.

My teacher says I have to buy a lamp with a remote control and take that apart. But what should I get out of it to make sure it will do what I want?

Comment: Does the dance mat have anything or is it just a mat? You could use a light solution where if you stand and block the light, it changes the status of the light. Another possibility is to use some capacitive solution to sense someone on the mat. These are the sort of things you can investigate online.

Comment: no you can connect it to your computer, but i don't know if i can connect it to my computer and switch the light on via the computer.

Comment: Ok so the sensing part is basically done. Yes, the light I'm sure can be connected. With a relay for example. It depends on the kind of lamp you want to turn on.

Comment: You can get USB controlled power cords/strips.  With that and your dance mat, it's merely a software problem, provided the necessary programming information for both devices is available.

Comment: When you say "lamp" are you talking 120V AC?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options for this, either a step switch or [touch sensitive](http://www.touchandglow.com/product-p/t-302s.htm) switch only if the mat can conduct.

Here is normal [step switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XK7K8Y) which is pretty rugged, inexpensive and can hold up to students bouncing back and forth on the mat. The only issue is that it **stays on per step and has to be stepped on again to toggle it off**. You will most likely have to do what the previous poster mentioned and swap the internal switch out for a compression based switch shouldn't be too hard, but at least you'll have the housing and wiring already manufactured if you buy this.

Answer (score 1):

There was an excellent article on [hackaday](http://hackaday.com/2006/06/05/industrial-strength-dance-pad/) where someone had built their own Dance Dance Revolution pad. You might want to take a look at their [construction technique](http://www.inventgeek.com/projects/dancepad1/overview.aspx) and apply it to your design.

If I were to do it myself, I would use two metal plates separated by compression springs placed in metal posts that are slightly smaller than the spring's uncompressed size. This gives you a switch that is very solid and which will practically last forever. Since the actual switch itself is under no stress (the metal plates and the springs take all the compressive force) it should be reliable and allow you to use any microswitch, reed switch or whatever you want.  You can then take apart a USB keyboard or joystick or anything that already talks to the computer and wire your mat switch "in parallel" with the usb device's button that you want the mat to use.

If you don't want to use a computer (which is good, there's no need for a computer of any kind for this) you can use the switch contact to fire a triac or drive a relay which actually connects the lamp to power.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, you just need to find the answer that suits you.

For me, I would use my PC (and ebay), at least at first.

I would look at the connector on your dance mat and look at how I would connect it into my PC, for example if its an old playstation one, you can get a playstation to USB convertor that makes it appear as a gamepad to the PC.

For controlling lights, I would use a cheap DMX interface (for which programming libraries are available) and connect it a LED disco light, its gives you loads of flexibility and won't scare the teacher by working directly with mains!

This way you can concentrate on your functionality at first and have the choice of many different programming environments. (and most of them free)

And the last advantage is, whats bought on ebay maybe sold on ebay so after the project is over you maybe able to get some money back by selling the bits again!